# Get data X days ago with pgsql and doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on Symfony2 and i have an entity `Account` with a field `inscriptionDate` type `datetime`.

I need to retrieve the number of inscription X days ago, and i have some troubles, for now i have :

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('COUNT(a.id)')
            ->from('MyProjectBundle:Account', 'a')
            ->where('a.inscriptionDate = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ?1 DAY) ')
            ->setParameters(array(1 => $daysAgo));
    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

I have an error on `CURDATE()`. How can i do that ? I need to count all inscriptions on `NOW() - X days`, and i don't want to use `hour-minute-second` in my datetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DATE_DIFF](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#id3) instead of *DATE_SUB* to meet a condition like "X days ago".

For example:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('COUNT(a.id)')
   ->from('MyProjectBundle:Account', 'a')
   ->where('DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), a.inscriptionDate) > ?1')
   ->setParameters(array(1 => $daysAgo));

return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: I have an error : Expected known function, got 'DATEDIFF

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. It should be DATE_DIFF. I just updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the result is not good... if i check with $dayAgos = 10 i have 8 in result. But in database, my max date is"2014-07-15 16:17:13"